# Magazine style frontpage with multiple categories/loops and no duplicate posts

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, loop, get-posts, customization

I am migrating a static magazine site to wordpress. I would like to have a frontpage displaying multiple categories with a few posts in each, e.g "politics", "environment", "health" and "technology". On top of that I would like to have a "latest news" category. The posts displayed in the "latest news" category will also belong to another category (and child category e.g poltics-->asia-->india) and show up on a page with posts only from the specific category (e.g a "politics" page), but they cannot be duplicate posts on the frontpage as long as they show in the "latest news" category. The categories would be displayed in a grid magazine type design. An example of what I am trying to accomplish [is this site](http://falkvinge.net/), a well-known pirate party blog.

Can someone point me in the right direction how I would accomplish this? Basically I would need to be able to have maybe ten loops in the same page, without any duplicate posts. Very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a class specifically for passing data between widgets classes using static variables and it will work for your use case as well. Grab the class [here](http://coderrr.com/php-passing-data-between-classes/).

The way you would use this is as follows for each custom loop:

```
$exclude_ids  = IntermediaryData::get(); //Retrieve previous exclude IDs
$args['post__not_in'] = $exclude_ids;

//new WP_Query($args); Custom loop query

//Loop Start
     $exlude_ids[] = $post->ID,
//Loop End

IntermediaryData::set($exclude_ids); //Pass IDs to next loop
```

Comment: Thank you very much Brian. I will have a look at your suggestion. I have found a working solution at: http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-use-two-or-more-loops-without-duplicate-posts